# Installing Artifactory OSS port on FreeBSD jail

Tags: artifactory, freebsd, jail

I have installed artifactory-5.4.1 on a FreeBSD 11.1 jail.  I have localhost and a loopback interface defined, but its IP address is `127.0.0.169`.  When I install the artifactory package and attempt to start it, it fails to configure because it initially only allows the admin user to connect via `127.0.0.1`:

```
2017-10-20 14:52:04,177 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:97) - Application could not be initialized: HTTP response status 403:{
"errors" : [ {
"code" : "FORBIDDEN",
"message" : "User 'admin' is not allowed to login from remote address: 127.0.0.169"
} ]
}
```

Where can I modify the artifactory configuration so that admin is allowed to log in from a different IP address before this configuration takes place?

Comment: try using 'localhost' instead of ip (using hostname is preferred way in Artifactory documentation)
you can add `127.0.0.169 localhost` to your `hosts` file ( also see $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.config.xml in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files )